# How to add our own advetisement in my admob account

Tags: ios, admob

Hi i am using admob as advertisement in my iphone. I have create one app from sites/apps in from admob site. And i have integrated the admob in my project. but how to create new advertisement in my admob account. example . i have to display my company's advertisement then how can i do this. please help me.

Comment: there is Admob well explain about house ad please visit this : https://support.google.com/admob/answer/1619751?hl=en

Comment: @ Nitin Gohel hi i have follow this link and i have add new house add advertisement but now i want to test it on device but my new new house add is not displaying in the admob. please help.